# Custom zoomable images using Bing maps

Tags: c#, wpf, api, bing-maps

I want to use the Bing map WPF control and I'm wondering if it is possible to set our own "image source".
Basically I'd like to use the control to provide deep zoom functionality for various images that would be loaded by my application.

I know that it's possible with Google maps (as shown here: http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html#maps_code_tilesgen)
but I was wondering we can do something similar with Bing maps?

P.S.: I would prefer using Bing because Microsoft provides a native WPF control, something that Google doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add a custom map (or image) tile provider you would have to implement a [TileSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750702) and override its [GetUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.tilesource.geturi) method to provide the URI of an image tile.

See [Adding Tile Overlays to the Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868033) for the details. The code sample there is not that great, since some things they do in code could better be done in XAML, but it is a starting point.

Note however that even if you don't use Bing Maps content, using the WPF control forces you to use a [Bing Maps API Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709042). The control authenticates your key at the Bing Maps service provider, which will require an internet connection. Hence your image display application won't run in an offline environment, or to be more precise, it will run but display an ugly error message in the center of the control area.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
That means though, that the default bing maps will still be there and I'll just be adding a custom overlay over it?
Isn't there a way to completely scrap the bing maps and use my own custom image?

Comment: There is a way. Simply set the [Map.Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapcore.mode) property to [MercatorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mercatormode). Example code is in [MercatorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mercatormode).

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can and it's incredibly easy to do in Bing Maps. Microsoft has developed a tool called [MapCruncher](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/) that cuts a supplied image into tiles with the structure expected by Bing Maps. This is really important because, although Bing Maps and Google share the same tile structure, Bing Maps uses something called a quadkey to define each tile (meaning, the z-x-y of the tile).

Note: it's also possible to load tiles made for Google Maps in Bing Maps. You just need to tweak the tile source.

Anyway, better shown than said.

Here's a really detailed tutorial by the Microsoft Research team on using MapCruncher:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/tutorial/version3.0docs/index.htm

Comment: Thanks.
So I must use this tool to process my image then use the solution suggested by Clemens to implement it?

Comment: I just had a better look at the tool. The thing is that the MapCruncher needs reference to map my image with the bing maps. That is not exactly what I want since I simply want to discard the bing maps and use my own image.
Isn't there a way to just process my image into a tile format that can be understood by the map control?

Comment: Actually MapCruncher does not need Bing Maps. It just renders images on the filesystem. Then, on your map control (which could be powered by Bing Maps, Leaflet, or others), you create a tile layer pointing to those images...

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I still have to add "markers" to map the Source map (my image) with the Virtual earth position. If I understood correctly.

Comment: Correct. But that's really easy to do. I don't know if you've opened the tool or not, but you just click the map to add the points. If you want a simpler tutorial I've posted one in my blog some time ago: http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-1.html